# How to chose the true ones from database

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

Hey there i use psql with pgadmin4, How can i choose only the true ones

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What true ones?

Could you please mention the specific column for which you want to apply the true criteria?

As per the image attached by you, you can do:

```
select wpns_u, arm_u, hlm_u, boots_u from inventory where the_colum_you_want_to_put_conditions_on=true;
```

eg: for all the records where wpns_u = true you can do:

```
select wpns_u, arm_u, hlm_u, boots_u from inventory where wpns_u=true;
```

Comment: i mean, i want to check all the inventory and pick the ones that are true, for example hlm_u is false so i don't want that one   Thanks for your time

Comment: Ok, so as explained above you can put conditions on specific columns for which you want the value to be true or false.

for eg:

for all the inventories where hlm_u is false and wpns_u is true you can do:


`select wpns_u, arm_u, hlm_u, boots_u from inventory where wpns_u=true and hlm_u=false;`